# Creating pages or using single page design?

Tags: website-design, cms, file-manager

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this... Please redirect me to correct location if needed.

I'm creating a support page for my website, and I was wondering how most websites such as [twitter](https://business.twitter.com/en/basics/what-is-twitter/) deal with their design? Do they create a single pages for each question? Or is it one page and they use some kind of show/hide to toggle between each questions? I'm trying to figure out how I should build my website? If they use the "show/hide" method, how do they change the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference between single and multiple page for static content are page size and user's experience in navigation.

I can tell you multiple page would be better if mobile is one of your mobile platform and your content is large. Although mobile device has no problem in loading a fairly large page from wikipedia, it is much faster to load with a smaller page.

For the user experience please ask in [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not quite sure I agree with @neo as it really depends on the content. The overall page weight is made of all of the page assets and the text part of it is often only a small portion of that. So for example a very lightweight page design with a lot of text may be preferable for mobile depending on the context. Not having to navigate to a new page while on a slow loading mobile network would also need to be factored in.